# Correct way to handle pagination with firebase firestore in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I have a react view that subscribes to a Firestore collection. The collection could potentially be huge. Therefore I want pagination. From my understanding, since Firestore is a NoSQL DB, pagination needs to be done with [cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors). Some suggest that it's possible to use offset instead of cursors. But since using an offset is associated with [significant drawbacks](https://firebeast.dev/tips/do-not-use-offset), I would rather stick with a cursor-based pagination. From my point of view, cursors complicates the pagination logic a lot. I've developed a code that works quite well but has some drawbacks.

The solution I have developed depends on two arrays that contain the start and end document references on each page. This works for basic pagination and deletion of items. However, if I add an item, it will not update properly. I don't know where the added item will be placed since this depends on what `order` property I use. Likewise, the pagination will break if I delete an item not on the current view since the start and end document references won't update. Also, there is now way for the code to know if a document is added or deleted since its a realtime subscription and other client might changes the documets.

I can't figure out how to get this to work correctly. What's the best practice for pagination on a NoSQL db?

A snipped from the working code:

```js
 // Pagination
    const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState<number>(5);

    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState<number>(1);
    const [firstDocs, setFirstDocs] = useState<QueryDocumentSnapshot[]>([]);
    const [lastDocs, setLastDocs] = useState<QueryDocumentSnapshot[]>([]);

    const [constraints, setConstraints] = useState<QueryConstraint[]>([limit(itemsPerPage)]);

    const [canGoNext, setCanGoNext] = useState<boolean>(false);

    function resetConstraints() {
        setConstraints([limit(itemsPerPage)]);
        setSort({ key: 'added', title: 'Skapad', direction: 'desc' });
        setPageNumber(1);
    }


    function next() {

        if (lastDocs) {
            setConstraints([startAfter(lastDocs[pageNumber]), limit(itemsPerPage)])
            setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1);
        } else {
            console.log("Next error");
        }
    }

    function prev() {

        if (firstDocs) {
            setConstraints([startAt(firstDocs[pageNumber - 1]), limit(itemsPerPage)])
            setPageNumber(pageNumber - 1);
        } else {
            console.log("Prev error");
        }

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setConstraints([limit(itemsPerPage)]);
    }, [itemsPerPage]);


    // Course types
    const [courseTypes, courseTypesLoading, courseTypesError] = useCollection(query(collection(firestore, 'courseTypes'), orderBy(sort.key, sort.direction), ...constraints), {
        snapshotListenOptions: {
            includeMetadataChanges: true
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Update pagination");
        async function updatePaginationPossibilities(lastDoc: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {

            // Check if we can go forward
            const nextItemQuery = query(collection(firestore, 'courseTypes'), orderBy(sort.key, sort.direction), startAfter(lastDoc), limit(1));
            const nextSnapshot = await getDocs(nextItemQuery);
            const nextItemLength = nextSnapshot.docs.length
            //console.log("Next page has documents: " + nextItemLength);
            if (nextItemLength > 0) {
                setCanGoNext(true);
            } else {
                setCanGoNext(false);
            }

        };

        if (courseTypes) {


            const firstDoc = courseTypes.docs[0];
            let arrayFirst = firstDocs;

            arrayFirst[pageNumber] = firstDoc;
            console.log("FirstDocs: " + arrayFirst[pageNumber]);
            setFirstDocs(arrayFirst);

            const lastDoc = courseTypes.docs[courseTypes.docs.length - 1];
            let arrayLast = lastDocs;
            arrayLast[pageNumber] = lastDoc;
            console.log("LastDocs: " + arrayLast[pageNumber]);
            setLastDocs(arrayLast);

            updatePaginationPossibilities(lastDoc);

        } else {
            console.log("Course types undefined");
        }
    }, [courseTypes, sort.direction, sort.key]);
```